# bootstrap typeahead on input not displaying the key when a value is selected

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

How do I select the states.address and wanted to display the state.address but the ng-model selPcode to have the state.postcode instead?

Here is a working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qbp2gqep/. 
Here is the json array object:
     $scope.states = [{postcode:'B1',address:'Bull ring'},    {postcode:'M1',address:'Manchester'}];

Here is the html snippet: `postcode
        <input type="text" ng-model="selPcode" /> typeahead
        <input type="text" ng-model="selPcode" typeahead="state.postcode as state.address for state in states | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-editable="false" />`

I can either get the state.address or state.postcode but not the way I wanted i.e to display the state.address but internally the model should have the state.postcode.

Appreciate any help.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using ui-bootstrap typeahead as below

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" placeholder="Type your Address"
   uib-typeahead="state as state.address for state in states | filter:{address:$viewValue}"  
   class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0">
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3RwUaU6GKJsjmFbbtA6I?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks I am able to get it working with just typeahead="state as state.address for state in states | filter:.....

<code>
'<div class="container-fluid">
     postcode <input type="text" ng-model="selPcode.postcode" />
     typeahead <input type="text" ng-model="selPcode" typeahead="state as state.address for state in states | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-editable="false" />
    </div>
</code>

Comment: I m sorry didnt get you

Comment: It works, I accepted your answer. I didnt use uib-typeahead though just typeahead also works.

Comment: @Sansun Cool. is there anything else you want me to help you with?

Comment: Sorry I did it now :)